# Piping data to ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

Is it possible to directly pipe data to `ogr2ogr`? I'm trying to `curl` a GeoJSON file and pipe it to `ogr2ogr` to covert it to another format.

Without using a pipe, I was able to achieve this by first writing a file and then converting it using the following command, but I'm curious if it is possible to skip that step.

```
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson" -o "countries.geojson" && ogr2ogr -f "KML" countries.kml countries.geojson
```

I also tried creating a variable with the curl output instead of piping it, but `ogr2ogr` was not able to read it:

```
DATA=$(curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson") && ogr2ogr -f "KML" countries.kml $DATA
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OGR has its own idiom for stdin, `/vsistdin/`. Use that as ogr2ogr's first argument (the dst_datasource_name) and you can pipe curl's output to it:

```
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson" | ogr2ogr -f "KML" countries.kml /vsistdin/
```

Comment: At least on Windows it works also like this: `ogrinfo -ro -al -so /vsicurl/http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/ogr/data/poly.shp` Other examples at http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/ReadInZip

Comment: Documentation now moved to https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html.

Answer (score 11):

You can use URLs as paths to OGR data sources, so you don't need curl or pipes.

```
ogr2ogr -f KML countries.kml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson
```

Comment: That's awesome! I had no idea that was a possibility. This is a cleaner solution than the accepted answer, but the question was explicitly about piping into ````ogr2ogr````.

Comment: Good one, Mike! I wouldn't call either of them super clean (ogr2ogr putting the destination coming before the source bugs me). Treating a URL as a local file works... until it doesn't. And curl has a lot of options (verbose mode, security) that ogr2or doesn't.

Comment: The source files being listed last is a reasonable choice, because there can be more than one.